# JAVA: Simple pop does only return first item

Tags: java, stack

I got following code set up:

```
public class ListStack implements Stack {
    private class List {
        List next;
        Object object;

        public List(Object o, List n) {
            object = o;
            next = n;
        }
    }

    private List firstItem;
    private int size;

    public ListStack() {
        firstItem = new List(null, null);
        size = 0;
    }

    public List getEnd() {
        List endEl = firstItem;

        while (endEl.next != null) {
            endEl = endEl.next;
        }
        return endEl;
    }

    public boolean push(Object o) {
        List e1 = new List(o, null);
        this.getEnd().next = e1;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (this.firstItem.next == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            List endEl;
            List tempEl;

            endEl = this.getEnd();
            tempEl = firstItem;
            while (tempEl.next != endEl) {
                tempEl = tempEl.next;
            }
            tempEl.next = null;
            size--;
            return tempEl.object;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack s = new ListStack();

        Object test = new Object();
        Object test2 = new Object();

        System.out.println("pushing Object test to List: " + s.push(test));
        System.out.println("pushing Object test2 to List: " + s.push(test2));

        System.out.println("popping Object from List: " + s.pop());
        System.out.println("popping Object from List: " + s.pop());
        System.out.println("popping Object from List: " + s.pop());
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
 public interface Stack {  
     public int size();
     public boolean push(Object o);
     public Object pop();
 }
```

But its only giving me the first object and twice "null" but it should give me the two objects :( where is my mistake? It is asking for the last item and gives it back (.object) but only returns first object adress

Comment: Mistake #1: posted link to code instead of relevant code...

Comment: Could someone please translate the comments from German to English?

Comment: @WChargin removed the comments in an edit, they were standard "what this method does" type comments.

Comment: Hi! Shouldn't your `pop()` function return `endEl.object`?

Comment: @choice_sk: i think this is the solution , Try to write it an answer :)

Comment: As an aside, it's not a good idea to create classes with the same name as frequently-used standard Java classes: e.g. "List". Also, use names that describe the class better. The thing you are calling a List is not a list at all. if you called it "ListEntry" or "Node" it would be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is way too long-winded. A *stack* is a data structure that can efficiently *push* and *pop* elements. But your code has to traverse the whole stack for both operations (i. e. runs in *O(n)* instead of *O(1)* time.).

Prepending to your list is much more efficient as appending.

Example for an efficient push:

```
public void push(Object o) {
    firstItem = new List(o, firstItem);
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what your `pop()` function should return is `endEl.object`.